# Using 'new' in a projection?

Tags: c#, design, coding-style, linq, semantics

I wish to project a collection from one type (`Something`) to another type (`SomethingElse`).  Yes, this is a very open-eneded question, but which of the two options below do you prefer?

**Creating a new instance using `new`:**

```
var result = query.Select(something => new SomethingElse(something));
```

**Using a factory:**

```
var result = query.Select(something => SomethingElse.FromSomething(something));
```

When I think of a projection, I generally think of it as a *conversion*.  Using `new` gives me this idea that I'm creating new objects during a conversion, which doesn't feel right.  Semantically, `SomethingElse.FromSomething()` most definitely fits better.  Although, the second option does require addition code to setup a factory, which could become unnecessarily compulsive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can shorten down the second option using the factory method itself as action: `var result = query.Select(SomethingElse.FromSomething);`

Comment: @Spoike:  You are correct, but my example was just trivial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question appears to be more about the appropriateness of using a factory method over a straight constructor call. My favorite example uses the `TimeSpan` type because it has several constructor overloads and several FromXXX static factory methods.

```
// how easily can you spot the bug?
int[] durationMs = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

IEnumerable<TimeSpan> durations1 = 
    durationMs.Select(ms => new TimeSpan(0, 0, ms));

IEnumerable<TimeSpan> durations2 =
    durationMs.Select(ms => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ms));
```

Which expression was the bug easier to spot in the two equivalent projections? Fixing the two expressions is also interesting:

```
// spot the bug after the fix?
IEnumerable<TimeSpan> durations1 = 
    durationMs.Select(ms => new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, ms));

IEnumerable<TimeSpan> durations2 =
    durationMs.Select(ms => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms));
```

The `durations2` expression is correct (bug fixed). However, adding just one 0 parameter to the `durations1` constructor call was not enough - we have to add another 0 - going from the 3 parameter version to the 5 parameter version in order to specify milliseconds (as documented on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)).

The "Framework Design Guidelines" book has some [great advice on when to provide static factory methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1519446/119236). The book goes into more detail on each point whereas the link I provided merely summarizes the advice. Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent answer with a perfect example - I will use this in future :)

Answer (score 3):

In .NET Framework, the most frequently used convention is:

```
something.ToSomethingElse();
```

Examples:

- `37.ToString();`
- `new [] { "Hello", "World" }.ToArray();`
- `DateTime.Now.ToBinary();`
- `Guid.Empty.ToByteArray();`
- etc.

Note that depending on the context, maybe you could simply use [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
var result = query.Cast<SomethingElse>();
```

If you have a good reason to avoid this convention (for example if `SomethingElse` is a string), then use whatever convention you prefer from the ones you quoted in your question. They are both valid.

---

Another nice thing in C# is the implicit operator. For example, instead of:

```
var element = new XElement(new XName("section"), ...);
```

you simply write:

```
var element = new XElement("section"); // Uses implicit conversion from string to XName.
```

Comment: `something.ToSomethingElse()` would mean that the responsibility and logic of creating a new `SomethingElse` would reside in `Something`.  Surely this is not correct?  My reasoning: **A)** We might not always be able to extend `Something`, **B)** Constructing new instances (factories/constructors) should naturally lie within the class in question, and **C)** What if we can create a `SomethingElse` from many different other types?  Then we would have factory logic spread all over instead of in one place.

Comment: @davenewza: this is still the convention used by .NET Framework itself. As I said, you're not forced to use it and use one of your conventions.

Comment: `Cast()` most likely won't work, it doesn't call cast operators.

Comment: @davenewza agree 100% with everything you said in your comment. I always favour the factory method approach

Comment: Dave, I agree with you in part, but you can also implement the .ToSomethingElse as an extension method which would avoid polluting the original class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the second approach is that it requires a *named* (as opposed to an *anonymous*) type; otherwise, it would be impossible to pass `something` to a factory method. A large percentage of non-trivial LINQ queries use anonymous types, for example

```
query.Zip(otherQuery, (a, b) => new {First = a, Second = b}).Select(...)
```

or

```
query.Select((v,i)=> new {Value=v, Index=i}).Where(...).Select(...)
```

and so on. Having to define a named type for the anonymous type or using a generic `Tuple<...>` would solve the problem at the expense of readability.

Using `new`, on the other hand, lets you stay consistent even when you enter the territory of non-trivial LINQ queries. I would definitely recommend staying with `new`, and avoid making the matters that are already complex even more complex for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change one type to another type but dont want to above code every time .. use automapper .It does these translation and more code reuse can be possible through it.

http://www.automapper.org/

let me know if you need highlight on same.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would either go with the first option if it's only used in one place, or create an extension method if it is used in multiple places.